# How to add a do block in Mapbox map?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to add the do block below to show all the books in the map. I'm using Mapbox for the map but I'm not too sure how to show each pin for the book. I have it showing one pin for a random location as of right now but would love to have each book pin show. Any pointers?

```
<% @books.each do |book| %>
 <%= book.longitude %>
 <%= book.latitude %>
<% end %> 

<script>
 mapboxgl.accessToken = '<%= ENV['MAP_BOX_TOKEN'] %>';
 var geojson = {
 "type": "FeatureCollection",
 "features": [
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "message": "Foo",
            "iconSize": [60, 60]
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                -118.270204,
                34.086941
            ]
        }
    }
  ]
};
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
 container: 'map',
 style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
 center: [-118.270204, 34.086941],
 zoom: 15
});

// add markers to map
geojson.features.forEach(function(marker) {
 // create a DOM element for the marker
 var el = document.createElement('div');
 el.className = 'marker';
 el.style.backgroundImage = 'url(<%= image_path "marker.svg" %>)';
 el.style.width = marker.properties.iconSize[0] + 'px';
 el.style.height = marker.properties.iconSize[1] + 'px';

// add marker to map
 new mapboxgl.Marker(el, {offset: [-marker.properties.iconSize[0] / 2, -marker.properties.iconSize[1] / 2]})
    .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
    .addTo(map);
});
map.scrollZoom.disable();
map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl());
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it with the code below.

```
<script>
 mapboxgl.accessToken = '<%= ENV['MAP_BOX_TOKEN'] %>';

 var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
 container: 'map',
 style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
 center: [-118.270804, 34.086241],
 zoom: 15
});
<% @books.each do |book| %>
 var geojson = {
 "type": "FeatureCollection",
 "features": [
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "message": "Foo",
            "iconSize": [60, 60]
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                <%= book.longitude %>, <%= book.latitude %>
            ]
        }
    }
  ]
};

// add markers to map
geojson.features.forEach(function(marker) {
 // create a DOM element for the marker
 var el = document.createElement('div');
 el.className = 'marker';
 el.style.backgroundImage = 'url(<%= image_path "marker.svg" %>)';
 el.style.width = marker.properties.iconSize[0] + 'px';
 el.style.height = marker.properties.iconSize[1] + 'px';

// add marker to map
 new mapboxgl.Marker(el, {offset: [-marker.properties.iconSize[0] / 2, -marker.properties.iconSize[1] / 2]})
    .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
    .addTo(map);
});

<% end %>

map.scrollZoom.disable();
map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl());
</script>
```